# Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36) when knitting an rmarkdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When I knit an rmarkdown file, I get the following error message:

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36)
Execution halted
```

I have previously been able to knit rmarkdown files without issue. I tried making a new file and running it without making any changes to the base template but still had the same issue. I have run different files that are in different locations on my computer but all have the same issue. I've found others having a similar issue however their character strings seem to all be related to the '\' character for file locations but I am not sure what `(<input>:4:36)` means. I don't have any file location strings in the file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I have now found that I am able to use `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")` to knit the file from the console but still have the same problem when using the Knit button.